# Can't use share image button due to error code: Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an share image button, but for some reason I'm getting such a **error code:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /document/image:74
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
        at com.jawad.photoeditor.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:163)
```

my **Manifest** looks like:

```
<provider>
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
</provider>
```

and my **fileprovider.xml** looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

And my **specific code** looks like :

```
final Button shareButton = findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
                intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Tried this, but it didn't resolve the issue. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've just tried adding an root path in my xml file.

```
<root-path name="root" path="." />
```

and it now works as a charm. Issue solved